# Unable to ping Oracle virtual box Host to Guest

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have installed 3 guest server in Oracle Vbox  on Host (nn1).(Guest servers Dn1,Dn2 & Dn3)and Host is nn1 .

I can ping nn1 from these Guest's but i'm unable to ping Guests from host nn1.
When I'm trying to ping guests raising below error from Host.Please let me know a solution to make a connection with guests from host.Thanks in advance.

```
 [root@nn1 ~]# ping Dn1
    PING Dn1 (10.88.12.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable  
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable


    [root@nn1 ~]# ping Dn2
    PING Dn2 (10.88.13.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable

   [root@nn1 ~]# ping Dn3
    PING Dn3 (10.88.14.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.88.12.0 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: How is your NIC configured? NAT? Bridge? Host-Only?

Comment: I have configured 2 adaptors for each Guest.

Please check below images for the Network configuration of One of Guest .This is same for all the guests.

[IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/2nthgs9.jpg[/IMG]

[IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/120otps.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: I'm guessing your host machine is Linux, can you try and check your routes? (post the output of `route -n`)

Comment: Thanks for the update Yaron.Yes our host is on Linux .

Comment: Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 vboxnet1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

Comment: You have 2 routes to the same gateway, check your setting, you have more than 1 host-only networks, both of them on the same IP range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99201/discussion-between-yaron-and-saikumar-a).

Comment: Sure Yaron.Lets continue over chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is duplicate routing definitions.

Delete vboxnet0 to remove the route and the NIC so packets won't be "trapped".